# overwriting css class

Tags: css

Little trouble in using css, in the below code, i have used odd and even classes of css to change the background color. But whenever there is a backup(as highlighted) it should display the values as italics along with the odd and even properties. how to achieve this ?

```
<c:forEach items="${as.value.connections}" var="circuit" varStatus="elements">
                    <c:set var="stylesheetclass" value="primaryLine"/>
                    <c:set var="icon" value="/images/primary.png"/>
                    <c:if test="${circuit.backup}">

> <c:set var="stylesheetclass" value="backupLine"/>
> 
> 
> <c:set var="icon" value="/images/backup.png"/>

                    </c:if>



> <tr class="${elements.index % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">


                        <td >
```

Comment: Are you asking ,on mouse hover u need to display the values as italics along with the odd and even properties

Comment: its a complete list of items which needs to be displayed in a report, and i have used odd and even styles to display the rows with different background colors, but when there is a backup value, only that particular value i want to display as italics

Comment: Please clarify your question. What problem are you currently experiencing? Do your 'backup' rows have two classes in the outputted HTML, e.g. `<tr class="odd backup">`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, as I am not a typical web developer but a backend devleoper. All the rows needs to adopt the odd and even background properties, but wherever backup values are there, then the font should be "italics"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you make the functionality as if that a new class is added in the `<tr>` when **backup** value is present. For example if you add a class named `backup` then the  `<tr>` would look like this `<tr class="odd backup"> or <tr class="even backup">`. After doing this functionality add the styles like below :-

```
tr.odd {
    /* your styles already used*/
}
tr.even {
    /* your styles already used*/
}
tr.backup {
    font-style: italic; /* This would take effect for the <tr> which has backup class added */
}
```

Edit:

If you place the styles which you want to keep for the backup `<tr>`inside the `.backup` class your requirement would be achieved. **And please keep the `.backup` class below the `.even and .odd` class. As styles written above gets overwritten with the below ones.**

Comment: which script are you using? As I am not aware of what you are using. I am a front end developer hence given you the idea related to styles.

Comment: Ohh I don't have knowledge on JSP, you can rais a question for this requirement. And once you get an answer on that use the style as I have mentioned here. Your issue would be solved.

Comment: it worked after making few changes in the script conditions and creating .backup in the css...thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

used this one `!important`

```
tr.odd{
background:red !important;
}
```

---

```
tr.even{
background:yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it just with css selectors, you don't need to specify the classes in the DOM.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

and then just add the class of backup when you want.

Just make sure you define the `.backup` class after the even and odd rules, so nothing becomes overwritten.